# scroll pic with fixed position

Tags: css, scroll, jscrollpane

Good day, I'm having a problem achieving scrolling image with fixed position.
I have done half way of achieving what i wanted by creating two background images with fixed positions, (1 is normal, 2 is gray scaled).

once i upload it into wp site, they stay in background + they stay positioned at the top left of the page, (even after i specify their location, but images fixed to the view port, which what i don't want).

here's the link of my code: `[https://jsfiddle.net/rf759hw3/1/][1]`

now what i wanted to achieve is:
1 - keeping images in specified position while scrolling.
2 - once i reach to page section which has image, only then scrolling start from greyscale, to original (not while i scroll the page itself).

i found a website which achieve same concept which I'm looking to achieve:

http://tnc.org.cn/#TNC#events (the river section)

but their heavily filled with JS with many dependencies, and i am not yet  familiar with js btw.

after days of research i found something which can achive my purpose using js called ["Magic Scroll"](http://scrollmagic.io/) , but i couldn't find an example which suites my purpose to achieve, which is keeping my images in position as i scroll and overlap one another when i reach their section , any advice or help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Google javascript parallax. You aren't really going to achieve that without at least some js.

Comment: Where's your example? Seems you forgot to paste a link.

Comment: @Rvervuurt sorry, my mistake, im not allowed to post more than 2 links, i edited my example, thought it was linked to jsfiddle
@ RickCalder i edited my example link, in my example i achieved the parallax like with css position fixed for both images, and its wokred, now my concern is that i need it to be stick to its position place because by default its just background without location in page